# Spring batch admin web app Job listing

Tags: spring-batch-admin

I would like to see all the jobs in one page and how can I list more than 20 jobs (default size) in Spring batch admin web app?  Also is there a way to sort the jobs by name when listing?

Answer (score 1):

Copy 'jobs.ftl' file from Spring-batch-admin-manager jar to a folder 
WebContent\WEB-INF\web\manager\jobs\html in your workspace. Modify the below line in the file by adding the "?sort_by("name")" to the list. It will sort the jobs that are in current page only. I am looking for a way to display more than 20 jobs so that this way all jobs can be sorted.

<#list jobs?sort_by("name") as job>